# In object-oriented R programming, what is an "active binding"?

Tags: r, oop, r6

In object-oriented R programming (especially Winston Chang's R6 package), what is an [active binding](https://rpubs.com/wch/24456)?

Comment: `help.search("active binding")` > `?bindenv` > *Examples*

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: While this is probably a correct technical description, it is not very enlightening for someone who doesn't already understand what a binding is...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First it is probably best to understand what a "binding" is.  If we run code like:

```
x <- 5
```

then what has happened inside the computer is that we have put the value of 5 into a slot of memory and we have also 'bound' the name "x" to that location and value so that later we can use `x` and it will go to that memory location and look up the value (which is 5 until we change it to something else).  This is called a static binding because the value does not change unless the program specifically makes a change.

An active binding is similar in that we bind a variable name (like "x") to something, but that something is not just a constant value, but rather a function that will be run every time we try to access `x`.  So you could bind the name "x" to a function that calls `rnorm` and then each time you access `x` you would see a different random normal value.

Another example, consider if we do something with static bindings like:

```
mydf <- data.frame( x=1:10, y=10:1 )
df.size <- nrow(mydf)
mydf <- data.frame(z=1:100)
```

Now the variable `df.size` has the number of rows of `mydf` when it was created, not how many rows it has now (since `nrow` was run once, then the result was put into the `df.size` variable as a static binding, it does not update with changes to the data frame).  If on the other hand we created an active binding between `df.size` and a function that ran `nrow(mydf)` then any time we looked at the "value" of `df.size` then it would show the current number of rows in `mydf` no matter how many times we change it.

Comment: Greg's examples describe how a symbol is bound to a 'data' variable or to a function, but in both cases the binding is static; a function is as much an R object (technically, S-expression, e.g., a CLOSXP) as an integer vector (INTSXP). R's active bindings are symbols that look like variables but act like functions with 'get' and 'set' functionality -- the `randomNo` symbol in Gabor's answer. It's always struck me as weird that an object system (reference classes or R6) would be based on this quirky 'experimental' feature (see `?makeActiveBindng`).

Answer (score 11):

**1) R** In R, the idea of an [active binding](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bindenv.html) is that **you can define something that looks like a variable but it actually invokes a function each time it is accessed**.

For example, after the `makeActiveBinding` statement below each time `randomNo` is used as a variable it calls the function specified in the second argument to `makeActiveBinding` (which in this case generates a normal random variate) and returns the function's value:

```
makeActiveBinding("randomNo", function() rnorm(1), .GlobalEnv)

set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
randomNo
## [1] -0.5604756
randomNo
## [1] -0.2301775
```

**2) R6** Similarly, in R6 an active binding looks like a field but it actually runs a function when accessed returning the value of the function.

Here is the example in (1) redone with R6 active bindings.  Note that each time the field `randomNo` is accessed the associated function (which generates a normal random variate) is  invoked and its value returned as the value of the field.

```
library(R6)
RandomClass <- R6Class("Numbers",
  active = list(
    randomNo = function() rnorm(1)
  )
)

set.seed(123)
randomObject <- RandomClass$new()
randomObject$randomNo
## [1] -0.5604756
randomObject$randomNo
## [1] -0.2301775
```

**3) R6 - second example**  Another example can be found in the R6 active binding documentation  [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html#active-bindings).  In that example, each time the field `x2` is accessed as if it were an ordinary field, there is a call made to the function associated with `x2` (without passing any arguments to it) and the value of `x2` is the result of running that function.

Comment: It might be better to expand the active binding example to show both the 'get' and 'set' capabilities, the `fred` example on `?makeActiveBinding`.

Comment: I don't think that would be appropriate. This is an answer to what active binding is in R6, not a complete tutorial on it.  I have already provided a link to the vignette where more details can be found.